# Entries limited by date range

Tags: templating, datetime

I'm trying to filter entries on the front end by a date range but no matter what I do I end up with no results, despite there being results in the, temporarily hard coded, date range I am using.

```
  {% set page = page ?? 1 %}
  {# set search parameter here #}
  {% set search = q ?? '' %}
  {# stage #}
  {% set stage = stage ?? '' %}
  {# date #}
  {% set start = now|date_modify('-16 week')|atom %}
  {% set end = now|date_modify('-1 week')|atom %}


  {% set entryQuery = craft.entries
    .section('projects')
    .limit(limit)
    .stage(stage)
    .startDate(['and', '>= #{start}', '< #{end}'])
    .search(search) %}
    
    {% for entry in entries %}
      {% include '_includes/project-listing-card' %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The code above sets some parameters based on the url and defaults. Without the `.startDate` line this outputs entries as expected. However once I add in the startDate (a date field) nothing gets output.

How do I output entries that are in the date range?

Comment: I think you need to use double quotes for string interpolation, so `">= #{start}"` and `"< #{end}"`.

Comment: @SteveRowling that fixed it, if you make this an answer, I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String interpolation in Twig only works with double-quoted strings.

Change the `.startDate` line to `.startDate(['and', ">= #{start}", "< #{end}"])` and it should work.